# How to solve this integral: $\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}dx$?

Tags: integration

How do i integrate the following definite integral :

$\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}dx$. Any hint is appreciated. where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers.