# Integrating by parts with exponential and power-law functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a question about integrating by parts for
$$\int_{L}^{U}\left[x^{a} \cdot e^{-bx}\right]\,dx$$
for positive reals $L,U$ with $L<U$  ($L, U \in [0, +\infty) $). I'm interested in cases with $a$ and $b$ positive constants, either integer or non-integer.

```
case 1 : a and b are positive integers

case 2 : a and b are positive non-integers
```

Are there formulas that can give solutions for any given $a$, $b$, $U$, and $L$?

Incomplete gamma function is similar as this, but it is a special case of $b = 1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants?

Comment: yes, a and b are given constants.

Comment: If possible, who can tell me how to type mat formulas here ? thanks !

Comment: I've converted your question into symbolic form via Mathjax. I'm not sure it's quite right, though: did you mean $e^{a-1}$ or $e^{(a-1)x^{-b}}$? It wasn't clear from your original text. For a Mathjax tutorial, see this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: @user3601704 Then you can take $e^{a-1}$ out as a constant and integrate $x^{1-b}$ quite easily. But given that you reference the incomplete gamma function, I don't feel as though that's what you want.

Comment: It is likely intended to type something else. If the intended function has shape $x^p e^{-qx}$, one can make the change of variable $t=qx$. If you have $\exp(-qx^r)$ a change of variable will also work.

Comment: I have a typo here.

Comment: @user3601704 Here's a formatting tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user3601704 If $a$ & $b$ are constants then $e^{-b}$ is too & you can integrate $x^a$ as you would any polynomial: $\int ax^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1}, n\neq-1$.

Comment: @EulCan, OP has been updated again, thanks !

Comment: @user3601704 This page gives a solution for $L=0$, $U=+\infty$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601900/how-to-solve-this-integral-int-0-infty-xa-e-bxdx .

Comment: thanks ! what if $L, U \in [0, +\infty) $ ?

Comment: If $L\gt 0$, then one uses the incomplete gamma function, after the change of variable $t=bx$.