# General formula for evaluating integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-bx}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Find a general formula for evaluating integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}dx.$

I've been pondering about this question for some time. Obviously integration by parts is way too inefficient. I know there's recursion involved and maybe there's a way to find a general formula through intuition.

Comment: Try to make a recurrence on the positive integer a, I think.

Comment: Use integration by parts $a+1$ times, using each time the exponential term as $\frac{dv}{dx}$ and the power-of-$x$-term as $u(x)$.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this integral: $\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601900/how-to-solve-this-integral-int-0-infty-xa-e-bxdx)

Comment: I think this version should be closed as a duplicate of the older version. Exceptions to that tendency can be justified if A) the newer version has more context and/or is otherwise a better, B) has better answers. Neither applies in this case in my opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}\,dx=\frac1{b^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty y^ae^{-y}\,dy
=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{b^{a+1}}$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
The gamma function satisfies
$$\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$$
and so for integers $n\ge0$,
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!.$$

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Use the change of variables $u=bx$ and then use the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: How was this asked in 2019 and answered in 2013??

Comment: @DavidRaveh An older question was merged with this question, so the answers to the old question show up on this question too. Or as the next commenter will say, time travel.

Comment: First proof of time travel existing @DavidRaveh

Comment: @SBF yes, we should forward this to the string theorists

Answer (score 6):

You can do this nicely using the Feynman trick: let
$$I(y) = \int_0^\infty e^{yx}e^{-bx} dx$$
Compute this integral (for $y<b$ and $b\ge1$). Then
$$\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-bx}dx=\left.\frac{d^a}{dy^a}\right|_{y=0}I(y) = -a!b^{-a-1}$$
I leave it to you to fill in the details (and to show that it is allowed to exchange the integral with the $a$ derivatives in $y$).

Answer (score 4):

Example: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-2x}dx$ using the shortcut to multiple "integration-by-parts":
$$\begin{align}
x^3 \quad &\searrow^+ \quad e^{-2x}\\
3x^{2} \quad &\searrow^- \quad -e^{-2x}/2\\
6x \quad &\searrow^+ \quad e^{-2x}/4\\
6 \quad &\searrow^- \quad -e^{-2x}/8\\
0 \quad &\;\;\;\;\;\; \quad e^{-2x}/16\\
\end{align}
\\
$$
$\text{such that}\;\displaystyle \int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-2x}dx=\left[-x^3\frac{e^{-2x}}{2}-3x^2\frac{e^{-2x}}{4}-6x\frac{e^{-2x}}{8}-6\frac{e^{-2x}}{16} \right]_0^\infty$

$\mathbf{Note:}$ The above process is tedious for large a and/or b. It is then preferrable to switch to the gamma function instead.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for $a\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
F(a,b)
&=\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac1b\int_0^\infty x^a\,\mathrm{d}e^{-bx}\\
&=\left[-\frac1bx^ae^{-bx}\right]_0^\infty+\frac ab\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{a}{b}F(a-1,b)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and when $a=0$,
$$
\begin{align}
F(0,b)
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-bx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1b\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Now, check the first few values of $a$ to see if a pattern emerges:
$$
F(0,b)=\frac1b\\
F(1,b)=\frac1b\frac1b\\
F(2,b)=\frac{2\cdot1}{b^2}\frac1b\\
F(3,b)=\frac{3\cdot2\cdot1}{b^3}\frac1b
$$
When you see a pattern, e.g. $\frac{n!}{b^n}\frac1b$, prove it using induction (and $(1)$ and $(2)$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at the definition of the Gamma function and consider what substitution might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a simplistic shortcut compared to previous answers, but hey, I guess the more the merrier: you can use the facts that

- the Laplace transform of $f(t)=t^n$ is $F(s)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$
- in general the Laplace transform is defined as $\int_0^\infty{e^{-st}f(t)dt}$

Obviously sub $t=x$, $s=b$ and $n=a$ into the first bullet point and you are home and dry.

Answer (score 0):

Generating functions also work.

With a slight change of notation define,
$$I(m,n)=\int_0^{+\infty} x^n e^{-mx}\ dx,\quad G(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I(n,m)}{n!}t^n,$$
we have,
$$\begin{align*}
G(t)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{I(m,n)}{n!}t^n=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-mx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(xt)^n}{n!}\ dx\\&=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-mx}e^{xt}\ dx =\int_0^{+\infty} e^{(t-m)x}\ dx=\frac{1}{m-t}
\end{align*}$$
for $t<m$. Expanding the result as a geometric series in the same region,
$$\frac{1}{m-t}=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{1-t/m}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{m^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{m^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!}{m^{n+1}}\frac{t^n}{n!}$$
comparing coefficients,
$$I(n,m)=\left[t^n/n!\right]G(t)=\frac{n!}{m^{n+1}}.$$

Answer (score -1):

I think we need to assume that $b$ is a positive real number. Let us make the substitution $u=bx$. Then
$\small\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-bx}dx=\frac{1}{b^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty u^ae^{-u}du$

Here, the integral $\int_0^\infty u^ae^{-u}du$ is convergent iff $\Re a>-1$,  $a\in\Bbb C$ and by definition of Gamma function, it is equal to $\Gamma(a+1).$

Comment: General formula is downvoted.